error in django application packaged with pyinstaller version > 5.1
Greetings to the community.
I have an issue that is driving me nuts for a long time now.
I have a Django application and I am trying to package it with pyinstaller (Windows). Everything works when I use Pyinstaller 5.1, which is quite old.
With any pyinstaller version above 5.1, I am getting the following error

To make it even weirder, in the more recent versions of pyinstaller it works when using the --console=True option.
But i don't want the console to appear in my packaged application. With --console=False, I am still getting the error.
Tried to use both python 3.11 and 3.12, i doubt it has anything to do with the python version.
From what I could gather from my limited Django knowledge, the NoneType is one of the Django basic models like the User, which are not supposed to be None hence the weird bug.
I am sorry, I cannot provide any code from the Django app.
Anyone has any idea (so I can start looking somewhere) would be highly appreciated, because now I really don't know what to look for.
Thanks
